# use of noexcept with constexpr function

Tags: c++

In Scott Meyers' "Effective Modern C++", he gives the following function to find the size of an array:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(T (&)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}
```

What is the purpose of the 'noexcept' here? As I understand it, noexcept only affects the generation of run time code - but I can't see any situation where this function could be called at run time rather than compile time?

Comment: If this function was not noexcept, it could cause the generation of default special function of some class not to be noexcept, then causing containers to use pessimized code to ensure exception safety. In this [exemple](https://godbolt.org/g/BKmM3n) the `struct x` is not nothrow default constructible, probably not one would have expected.

Answer (score 5):

In the general case, a template marked as `constexpr` may lose that status when instantiated. If a particular set of template arguments doesn't allow it, that qualification is silently removed, and the generated function is a "regular" one.

It's most likely specified like that to teach you a good habit. While it's true that a consexpr function is implicitly assumed non-throwing, if the constexpr status of the function is removed, it would still not interfere with correct `noexcept` specifications. When it's used as part of the expression being fed to the `noexcept()` operator.

Had it not been defined like that, it would skew exception specifications of functions that use it in their application of `noexcept()`. Because it's considered potentially throwing without the specification.

Since the `noexcept()` operator is evaluated at compile time too, it's not about code generation (as you phrased it) at all. It's more a matter of semantic correctness, akin to const correctness.

Comment: The thing is that constant expressions are considered non-throwing anyhow. So applying the noexcept operator to an invocation of arraySize will return true, even if there is no `noexcept` qualifier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/991fcd1cb348baef. So it is not considered "potentially throwing without the specification".

Comment: @NirFriedman - (A) A template functions constexpr status can be implicitly revoked if an instantiation doesn't allow it. Regardless of this overly simplistic case. (B) Which is why Myers may like to stress the general principle, which is to be `noexcept` correct by default.

Comment: Sure, I don't disagree with your comment, but then you should say that it's a good habit in general, etc. Your actual answer says that it could interfere with correct `noexcept` specifications, but this isn't true. The user here asked "what is the purpose of 'noexcept' **here**". I don't think the answer you gave here is correct, because the `noexcept` operator returns true regardless. If you still think it's correct, I'd like to see an example where removing `noexcept` from `arraySize` interferes with the correctness of another `noexcept` specification.

Comment: @Oktalist That's a bug in clang and nothing more.

Comment: @Oktalist If you're interested: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15481. I could have sworn there was a thread with more discussion but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Things changed in C++17 and I can find nothing in the current draft about constant expressions not being potentially-throwing ([except.spec]¶6)

Answer (score 0):

> but I can't see any situation where this function could be called at run time rather than compile time?

For example, simply with:

```
int a[42];

std::cout << arraySize(a);
```

we are not in a constant expression.

To force constexpr, you have to use something like:

```
int a[42];
constexpr auto size = arraySize(a);
std::cout << size;
```

Comment: Would `std::cout << arraySize(a);` not get compiled as `std::cout << 42;`?

Comment: It could by As-If rule (even if you remove `constexpr` BTW), but it is not required.

Comment: I think that `arraySize(a)` is a constant expression. Whether or not something is a constant expression does not depend on what it is assigned to; that merely affects whether it actually is guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time. In any case, as I noted above, `noexcept(arraySize(a))` returns true.

Comment: @Jarod42: Why might a compiler choose to evaluate this at runtime when it can be done at compile time?